# How do you select an element based on data in its child element?

Tags: jquery

If I have these two divs:

```
<div class="foo"><div class="bar" data-stuff="1"></div></div>
<div class="foo"><div class="bar" data-stuff="2"></div></div>
```

How do I select the div with class foo if given the parameter 2? I can do this:

```
$('.foo').find('[data-stuff=2]');
```

But I would only get the child element.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/closest/ `$('[data-stuff=2]').closest('.foo')`

Comment: The previous comment should be the answer, find the data you want then locate the parent/closest .foo

Comment: Please, correct you question. You are searching by attribute "data-stuff".

Comment: Works great, please add it as an answer so I can select it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, use some of these ways with the same result: (3rd one uses .parents() selector in case of many parent elements):

***Of course 'div[class^="foo"]' is equal to '.foo' in that case :) :)***

```js
var elems1 = $('[data-stuff="2"]').parent();
var elems2 = $('[data-stuff="2"]').closest('div[class^="foo"]');
var elems3 = $('[data-stuff="2"]').parents('div[class^="foo"]');

alert($(elems1).html());
alert($(elems2).html());
alert($(elems3).html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar" data-stuff="1">1</div>parent1</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar" data-stuff="2">2</div>parent2</div>
```

Playground : http://jsfiddle.net/upeqt2qw/

Comment: I selected this one as it uses the closest method, which is considered the best solution in this question.

Comment: I would choose closest too.I saw .parent() and say to myself why don't you present parent() and parents() selectors too...maybe this will help someone. Anyway,thanks for the vote.

Answer (score 3):

Select the element, then get its parent.

```
$('[data-stuff="2"]').parent()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call the parent method:

```
$('div.foo [data-stuff=2]').parent();
```